# ¿Cómo implementar UUID en PHP Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-5

Estoy empezando el desarrollo de una aplicación web para la empresa que trabajo y me exigen que utilice PHP Laravel (Soy nuevo en este Framework) y me encuentro con que debo usar UUID para las Key de cada tabla en la base de datos y esta por defecto usa enteros autogeneratos. Ya cree las migraciones y los modelos con UUID para las Key, pero al intentar hacer una prueba no encuentro un método que me genere el UUID.

No quiero usar ´uniqid´ ya que este me genera un código aleatorio máximo de 23 caracteres y el UUID cuenta es de 36 caracteres.

Comment: Existe una librería llamada laravel-uuid que puedes instalar con composer @antonio-lopez

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para usar UUID en Laravel existe una librería que puedes instalar con composer de la siguiente forma

```
 $ composer require webpatser/laravel-uuid
```

Nota: La debes ejecutar desde tu carpeta de proyecto.

Luego debes agregar un aliases en el archivo `app.php` que se encuentra dentro de la carpeta `config/app.php`. En este agregas lo siguiente:

```
 'Uuid' => Webpatser\Uuid\Uuid::class,
```

Para generar un UUID usa el siguiente código:

```
 Uuid::generate()->string;
```

Nota: Te recomiendo que todas las claves las llames `id` y al hacer relaciones solo renombres la llave foranea. Esto por que Laravel lo reconoce como la llave primaria.

Revisa este sitio que tiene mayor información por si tienes mas dudas o quieres ampliar el uso: https://medium.com/@steveazz/setting-up-uuids-in-laravel-5-552412db2088#.9wyaro8yp

Comment: Gracias me funcionó a la perfección @michael-traña

Answer (score 0):

Desde Laravel 5.6 está disponible la generación de UUid desde la clase Str.

```
$uuid = Illuminate\Support\Str::uuid();
```

Más sencillo y fácil imposible.

Esta clase extiende del paquete ámpliamente conocido y usado de Ramsey/Uuid.

Tienes más información aquí: [static UuidInterface uuid()](https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Support/Str.html#method_uuid)